# Rails 4 : Is there a better way to build the object: has_many through?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

> Controller: this is the part that I am not to happy about.

```
def new
    @incident = Incident.new 
    @patient  = Patient.find(params[:patient]) 
end

# This looks like trouble waiting to happen.
def create
    @patient  = Patient.find(params[:incident][:patient])
    @incident = Incident.new(incident_params)
    @incidentcases = current_user.incidentcases.build(:incident => @incident,:patient => @patient)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident.save
        @incidentcases.save 
        format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incident was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @incident }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

> Models:

```
    class Incident < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :incidentcases
      has_many :users,   through: :incidentcases
      has_many :patiens, through: :incidentcases
    end 
    class Incidentcase < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :patient
      belongs_to :incident
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :incidentcases
      has_many :incidents, through: :incidentcases
    end

    class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :incidentcases
      has_many :incidents, through: :incidentcases, dependent: :destroy

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :incidents, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    end
```

It has to be a better way of creating the object in the controller and have rails take care of it for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
@patient  = Patient.find(params[:incident][:patient])
@patient.incidents.build(incident_params)
if @patient.save
```

It should build the join record automatically.

Comment: Thanks,
That actually is kind of working. 
I need to add the current_user to it I though I could pass another  a ssociation to build like I am doing in the code above but it is complaining:
                @patient.incidents.build(incident_params, :user => current_user) 
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1). Hmm. Ill keep digging.

Comment: @lmcdougall You have an error because `build` method takes a hash parameter namely `attributes={}`, you can merge the hash and use `user_id` instead like so `@patient.incidents.build incident_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. I keep learning every time you guys help me.

The following change to code above gave me what I was looking for.

```
def create
    @patient  = Patient.find(params[:incident][:patient])
    @incident = Incident.new(incident_params)
    @incidentcases = current_user.incidentcases.build(:incident => @incident,:patient => @patient)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @incidentcases.save
```

This included the user_id that I was missing and it builded all the joins automatically.